# Ist "schwer zu angelnder" eine zulässige Satzkonstruktion?

Tags: grammaticality, participle

> Dieser Fisch ist schwer zu angeln.

ist ja wohl korrekt, oder? Dabei wird „schwer zu angeln“ prädikativ verwendet.

Wie steht's mit einer attributiven Verwendung durch ‚Partizipialbildung‘? Ist der folgende Satz auch korrekt?

> Aha, ein schwer zu angelnder Fisch!

Mir ist klar, dass das keine wirkliche Partizipialbildung ist, da man nicht von einem Verb ausgeht.

Wird diese Konstruktion in der Literatur verwendet? In welchen Kreisen? Und gibt es eine grammatikalische Beschreibung dieser Konstruktionen, etwa als eine Art Partizipialkonstruktion?

*Für Google*: ‘schwer zu angelnd’

Comment: Sehr interessante Frage. Die Konstruktion wird durchaus verwendet: "ein schwer zu verstehender Text", ein schwer zu ertragendes Schicksal", ich vermute aber, dass sie nicht korrekt im Dudensinn ist.

Comment: Es klingt seltsam, sollte aber passen. Ich würde sagen: "Ein schwer zu fangender Fisch" bzw. "Der Fisch ist schwer zu fangen" oder vielleicht "Der Fisch will sich nicht fangen lassen."

Comment: @Em1 Warum hast du den Titel ins Deutsche übersetzt? Verletzt ein englischer Titel bei deutscher Frage irgendwelche Gepflogenheiten?

Comment: @K.Stm. Was erwartest du denn persönlich, wenn du eine engl. Titelzeile liest? Ich erwarte dann englischen Text und nicht Deutsch oder sonst irgendeine Sprache. ;)

Comment: @Em1 Ich persönlich finde ja, stackexchange hat einen gewissen wissenschaftlichen Anspruch und daher sollten User hier des Englischen mächtig sein. Auf der anderen Seite ist die Frage derart fortgeschritten, dass es nichts ausmachen sollte, sie auf Deutsch zu stellen. Aber davon abgesehen: Solange man sich darüber nicht unterhalten hat, wie sprachlich konsistent man hier bleiben soll, bleibt es ja Geschmackssache, solange der Titel klar und treffend ist, was meiner war. Also finde ich das einen unberechtigten Edit. Schlimm ist's jetzt auch nicht, aber meiner Meinung nach gehört sich das nicht.

Comment: Ich glaube es wäre ein Gerundivum wenn es im Deutschen so etwas gäbe wie das Gerundivum im Lateinischen. Dann wäre es eigentlich "Der Fisch ist ein schwer zu angelnder [Fisch]", wobei das zweite "Fisch" ausgelassen wird. Ich glaube, das ist noch das logischste. Allerdings ist das dann eher die Zustandsbeschreibung, keine Eigenschaft. Also doch nicht 1:1 vergleichbar. Mmmmh...wir haben Sorgen...!

Answer (score 5):

Das Beispiel sieht auch für mich korrekt aus.

Zum Thema *grammatikalische Beschreibung*: Ich halte *schwer zu angelnder Fisch* für eine **[infinite Verbalphrase](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbalphrase#Beispiele_f.C3.BCr_infinite_Verbalphrasen)** mit einem Partizip Präsens als Kopf (vgl. das letzte Beispiel in der Quelle), in diesem Fall erweitert.

Comment: +1 Könnte auch irgendeine Grammatikalkonstruktion sein, die überhaupt keinen Namen mehr hat, wie auch der Konjunktiv in nicht allzu ferner Zukunft passé sein wird...sozusagen schwer zu benennende Konstrukte...komisch ist, dass das Wort "angelnder" einen Unterprozess in meinem Hirn anwirft, der den Eindruck hat, der Fisch würde angeln.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kann nur antworten als eine Person die Deutsch als Muttersprache hat, aber nie eine Deutsch-Stunde gehabt hat:

Es *klingt* jedenfalls korrekt =)

Comment: Ich stimme dieser Einschätzung zu. Ich habe zwar 12 Jahre Deutschunterricht ertragen müssen, habe mich als Schüler aber nie so richtig für die Theorie erwärmen können. Ich habe mir das, was ich heute über Grammatik weiß, autodidakrisch im Erwachsenenalter angeeignet. Ich weiß daher, dass diese Konstuktion gängig und daher zwangsweise korrekt ist, kann sie aber nicht benennen. (Warum ist das korrekt? Nicht der Gebrauch einer Sprache muss sich den Regeln beugen, sondern die Regeln geben den Gebrauch der Sprache wieder. Da diese Konstruktion im Alltag Verwendung findet ist sie also korrekt.)

Comment: Danke für die persönliche Einschätzung, aber eine wirklich konstruktive Antwort ist das nicht (aber natürlich auch keine schlechte, sodass man sie niedervotieren müsste). Man will ja jedoch eine Beobachtung anstellen, wie und wie bewusst diese Konstruktion verwendet wird, z.B. in der Literatur, und gucken, ob und wie diese Verwendung grammatikalisch festgehalten und beschrieben worden ist. Aber ich kann auch mal die Frage noch umstellen.

Answer (score 0):

Die Wendung ist wohl durchaus korrekt.

Im Gegenteil, wollte man den Satz äquivalent zu Phira's Beispielen ("ein schwer verständlicher Text" und "ein schwer erträgliches Schicksal") umformulieren, so wäre das vielleicht schöner, aber "ein schwer angelbarer Fisch" hört sich meines Erachtens zu gestelzt an.